# ggplot: adjusting alpha/fill two factors cdf

Tags: r, ggplot2, alpha, cdf

I'm having some issues getting my ggplot alpha to be sufficiently dark for my plot.

Example code:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=mpg, color=factor(gear), alpha=factor(carb))) + stat_ecdf()
```

[image]

As you can see, whenever `carb == 1`, it's very difficult to see the plot elements.  In my real world data set, the factor for color has four levels and the alpha factor has two levels.  I was hoping to have the alpha a slightly lighter shade of the color, but more visible than how it's occurring in that example).

Comment: look at the `range` argument of`?scale_alpha_discrete` ; ie `scale_alpha_discrete(range=c(0.4, 0.9))`

Answer (score 8):

You can adjust the alpha scale, as the user in the comment suggests, either by specifying a `range` or a specific set `breaks` to `scale_alpha_discrete`. That doesn't produce a very easy-to-read result, though:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=mpg, color=factor(gear), alpha=factor(carb))) + 
  stat_ecdf() + 
  scale_alpha_discrete(range=c(0.4, 1))
```

[image]

Another option would be to save `color` for the many-leveled factor and choose a different aesthetic for the few-leveled one, like maybe `linetype`

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=mpg, linetype=factor(gear), color=factor(carb))) + 
  stat_ecdf()
```

[image]

For readability, though, faceting might be a better bet.

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=mpg, color=factor(carb))) + 
  stat_ecdf() + facet_wrap(~gear, nrow=3)
```

[image]